# AJAX validate all fields again after resubmit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I have a register form which is handled by the validation helper from CodeIgniter. If the form validation returns false, it will return the errors as an JSON object.

So far the code is working just fine, but every time I try to resubmit the form with different details, it's just keeps adding those same errors on top of each other and it doesn't remove those error messages if I've typed correct values for the input fields.

What I need to do, is actually re-validate the form every time the submit button is pressed.

Here's what I have now.

**The AJAX part:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form#signup").on('submit', function(e) {
        var from = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: from.attr('action'),
            type: from.attr('method'),
            data: $(from).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.st == 0) {
                    for(var key in data.msg) {
                        // Add class and label with error message after input field 
                        $("form#signup input#" + key).addClass("input-error");
                        $("form#signup input#" + key).after("<label class='error'>" + data.msg[key] +"</label>");
                    }   
                    // Shake the register button
                    $("input#register").shake_it();
                } else {
                    alert("It works!");
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**Snippet from my register controller:**

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {    
    // If validation returns false, return errors as JSON
    $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('st' => 0, 'msg' => $this->form_validation->error_array())));
    return false;
} else {
    // Continue register process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the error messages at the beginning of the function:

```
$("form#signup").on('submit', function(e) {
    var from = $(this);

    $("form#signup input.input-error").removeClass("input-error")
                                      .nextAll(".error")
                                      .remove();

    //Ajax call
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be removing the previous class before adding a new one. So add

```
$("form#signup input#" + key).removeClass("input-error");
```

before

```
$("form#signup input#" + key).addClass("input-error");
```

This removes old errors & adds new error messages(if any) for every submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form#signup").on('submit', function(e) {
    $("form#signup input").removeClass('input-error'); // REMOVES input-error class from input fields
    $(".error").remove(); // Removes all error-spans from form.
    var from = $(this);
    ...
    ...
```

Line 2 and 3 here will remove errors from previous validations, and then the validation will be run again.